# Python 3.7 sqlalchemy ibm_db_sa ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

I used to connect DB2 through SQLalchemy in python. It stopped working and is throwing following error.

```
db2 = alch.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://UID:PW@g42-a-cmdpprod1.az2.ash.cpc.ibm.com:51000/cmdp;SECURITY=SSL;SSLCLIENTKEYSTOREDB=C:\\db2_ssl\\IBM_DB2_SSL_Client.kdb;SSLCLIENTKEYSTASH=C:\\db2_ssl\\IBM_DB2_SSL_Client.sth;SSLServerCertificate=C:\\Users\\KarthickK\\Downloads\\IBM_CLOUD.crt')
con = db2.connect()


File "C:\python373\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_sa\ibm_db.py", line 108, in dbapi
    import ibm_db_dbi as module
  File "C:\python373\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 45, in <module>
    import ibm_db
  File "C:\python373\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 17, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File "C:\python373\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 16, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
  File "C:\python373\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have added "IBM_DB_HOME" to environment variables

Versions:

Python - 3.7.3
ibm_db - 3.1.1
ibm_db_sa - 0.3.7
ibm_db_dbi - 3.1.1

Comment: Have you tried clearing out your __pycache__ files and doing a fresh run??

Comment: @High-Octane  I have cleared __pycache__ files and have tried again, still error persists